# How to allow exceptions when using Melander's DragDrop suite

Tags: delphi, exception, drag-and-drop

I am trying the `TDropFileTarget` component of Melander's [`DragDrop`](http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop/) suite. The goal is to carry out certain tasks after files are drag and dropped. Also, I would like to receive the exceptions if there is something wrong during processing.

It seems that the exceptions raised in the `OnDrop` event handler are swallowed. However, even after I put `raise` statements into the component's source code, I still cannot receive the exception. Could you help to comment?

#### The sample dfm file.

```
    object Form4: TForm4
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'Form4'
      ClientHeight = 270
      ClientWidth = 392
      Color = clBtnFace
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clWindowText
      Font.Height = -11
      Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
      Font.Style = []
      OldCreateOrder = False
      PixelsPerInch = 96
      TextHeight = 13
      object edt1: TEdit
        Left = 56
        Top = 72
        Width = 257
        Height = 21
        TabOrder = 0
        Text = 'edt1'
      end
      object dropfiletarget2: TDropFileTarget
        DragTypes = [dtCopy, dtLink]
        OnDrop = dropfiletarget2Drop
        Target = edt1
        OptimizedMove = True
        Left = 56
        Top = 120
      end
    end
```

#### The sample pas file.

```
    unit Unit4;

    interface

    uses
      Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
      Dialogs, DragDrop, DropTarget, DragDropFile, StdCtrls;

    type
      TForm4 = class(TForm)
        edt1: TEdit;
        dropfiletarget2: TDropFileTarget;
        procedure dropfiletarget2Drop(Sender: TObject; ShiftState: TShiftState; APoint:
            TPoint; var Effect: Integer);
      private
        { Private declarations }
      public
        { Public declarations }
      end;

    var
      Form4: TForm4;

    implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TForm4.dropfiletarget2Drop(Sender: TObject; ShiftState: TShiftState;
        APoint: TPoint; var Effect: Integer);
    begin
      raise Exception.Create('Error Message');
    end;

    end.
```

#### The original code of `TCustomDropTarget.Drop`.

```
    function TCustomDropTarget.Drop(const dataObj: IDataObject; grfKeyState: Longint;
      pt: TPoint; var dwEffect: Longint): HResult;
    var
      ShiftState: TShiftState;
      ClientPt: TPoint;
    begin
      FScrollTimer.Enabled := False;

      // Protect resources against exceptions in OnDrop event handler.
      try
        // Refuse drop if we have lost the data object somehow.
        // This can happen if the drop is rejected in one of the other IDropTarget
        // methods (e.g. DragOver).
        if (not Enabled) or (FDataObject = nil) then
        begin
          dwEffect := DROPEFFECT_NONE;
          Result := E_UNEXPECTED;
        end else
        begin

          ShiftState := KeysToShiftStatePlus(grfKeyState);

          // Create a default drop effect based on the shift state and allowed
          // drop effects (or an OnGetDropEffect event if implemented).
          if (FTarget <> nil) then
            ClientPt := FTarget.ScreenToClient(pt)
          else
            ClientPt := pt;
          dwEffect := GetValidDropEffect(ShiftState, ClientPt, dwEffect);

          // Get data from source and generate an OnDrop event unless we failed to
          // get data.
          try
            if (FGetDataOnEnter or GetData(dwEffect)) then
            begin
              if (not AsyncTransfer) then
                DoDrop(ShiftState, ClientPt, dwEffect);
            end else
              dwEffect := DROPEFFECT_NONE;
            Result := S_OK;
          except
            // We must not allow exceptions to escape from any of the COM methods since
            // COM doesn't support exceptions.
            dwEffect := DROPEFFECT_NONE;
            Result := E_UNEXPECTED;
          end;
        end;

        if (DropTargetHelper <> nil) then
          DropTargetHelper.Drop(DataObj, pt, dwEffect)
        else
          if (FDragImageHandle <> 0) and (FTarget <> nil) then
            ImageList_DragLeave(FTarget.Handle);
      finally
        // clean up!
        if (not AsyncTransfer) then
        begin
          ClearData;
          FDataObject := nil;
          FTarget := nil;
        end;
        FDropTargetHelper := nil;
      end;
    end;
```

#### The modified code of `TCustomDropTarget.Drop`.

```
    function TCustomDropTarget.Drop(const dataObj: IDataObject; grfKeyState: Longint;
      pt: TPoint; var dwEffect: Longint): HResult;
    var
      ShiftState: TShiftState;
      ClientPt: TPoint;
    begin
      FScrollTimer.Enabled := False;

      try
        // Protect resources against exceptions in OnDrop event handler.
        try
          // Refuse drop if we have lost the data object somehow.
          // This can happen if the drop is rejected in one of the other IDropTarget
          // methods (e.g. DragOver).
          if (not Enabled) or (FDataObject = nil) then
          begin
            dwEffect := DROPEFFECT_NONE;
            Result := E_UNEXPECTED;
          end else
          begin

            ShiftState := KeysToShiftStatePlus(grfKeyState);

            // Create a default drop effect based on the shift state and allowed
            // drop effects (or an OnGetDropEffect event if implemented).
            if (FTarget <> nil) then
              ClientPt := FTarget.ScreenToClient(pt)
            else
              ClientPt := pt;
            dwEffect := GetValidDropEffect(ShiftState, ClientPt, dwEffect);

            // Get data from source and generate an OnDrop event unless we failed to
            // get data.
            try
              if (FGetDataOnEnter or GetData(dwEffect)) then
              begin
                if (not AsyncTransfer) then
                  DoDrop(ShiftState, ClientPt, dwEffect);
              end else
                dwEffect := DROPEFFECT_NONE;
              Result := S_OK;
            except
              // We must not allow exceptions to escape from any of the COM methods since
              // COM doesn't support exceptions.
              dwEffect := DROPEFFECT_NONE;
              Result := E_UNEXPECTED;
              raise; // <--- Why can't I get the exception
            end;
          end;

          if (DropTargetHelper <> nil) then
            DropTargetHelper.Drop(DataObj, pt, dwEffect)
          else
            if (FDragImageHandle <> 0) and (FTarget <> nil) then
              ImageList_DragLeave(FTarget.Handle);
        finally
          // clean up!
          if (not AsyncTransfer) then
          begin
            ClearData;
            FDataObject := nil;
            FTarget := nil;
          end;
          FDropTargetHelper := nil;
        end;
      except
        raise; // <--- Why can't I get the exception
      end;
    end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't raise an exception in `Drop()` and catch it in your app's code.  Ander's original comment is clear about that:

```
// We must not allow exceptions to escape from any of the COM methods since
// COM doesn't support exceptions.
```

`Drop()` is `TCustomDropTarget`'s implementation of the `IDropTarget.Drop()` interface method. `IDropTarget` methods are called inside of the `DoDragDrop()` function, which is called by the app that initiated dragging.  `Drop()` runs inside your app's process, but it not called by your app.  So even if it were safe to raise an exception (which it is not), there is nowhere for you to place a `try/except` block to catch the exception, because the exception would be detected by COM and passed back as a failure to the initiating app, not your app.  Your only option is to handle errors in the `OnDrop` event handler without raising an exception.

Comment: Thank you very much for your knowledgeable comments! Could you help to suggest some materials where I can learn further what you said?

Answer (score 3):

Another option would be to - in your OnDrop event - simply collect the data needed (ie., the files dropped) and store them in a TStringList in your application, and then post a message to your form's message queue to inform it of the drop.

That way, the actual processing of the dropped files would be handled in your program's normal context and you can thus handle exceptions in the normal fashion.